# Why is my axios request gets cancelled twice in my useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Here's where I defined my API:

```
const controller = new AbortController()

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/posts/',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
    },
     signal: controller.signal
})
```

Here's my use effect code

```
 useEffect(() =>{

    api.get('/').then(res =>{
        console.log(res.data)
    })
    console.log('mounting')

    return () =>{
      controller.abort()

      console.log('unmounting')
    }
    

  }, [])
```

This is how my console was looking after I refreshed the page
[image]

I expect my cleanup function to run once right after the first render in this code before immediately re-running the `useEffect` and it seems like that's how it is, but why is my request cancelled twice?

Comment: Can you please post the full code, where is API defined, and what is the controller variable in the cleanup? Or maybe share a codesandbox.

Comment: @KaranBatavia I posted the `axios.create` and the controlller and I'm working on the sandbox

Comment: As far as I can see, when you refresh page your useEffect function is called twice. Beacause of that your cleanup function is called twice